# what is the style of command line editing used by the terminal emulator?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

in bash in gnome terminal in Ubuntu, the command line editing commands are by default emacs-style, and can be changed to vim-style.

In bash in the terminal emulator of Mac, the emacs-style commands don't work. Are the commands just those of a regular text editor?

Comment: n defaultI  Terminal and all Coca OSX apps you can edit using emacs keys e.g. Ctrl A and E for begin and end of line. The terminal editing is allowed by the shell which now defaults to bash.  The terminal in OSX and gnome terminal does not provide the command line editing

Comment: Thanks. commandline editing feature is provided by shell here bash not by the terminal emulator.  I will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X ships with `bash` and you will want to `set -o vi` to get vi-style commands. A very popular choice is `zsh` and the many customization packages like [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). Neither she'll is fully in either style by default.

For emacs style, it's similar - see [this great post for more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85396/8888):

> You switch between the two modes in bash, zsh or ksh with set -o vi or set -o emacs, and with bindkey -e or bindkey -v in tcsh or zsh.

Comment: I want to use emacs style. is the command `set -o emacs`?

Comment: @tim. Yes. See the edit and linked article